# use Onclick in extends PagerAdapter

Tags: android-studio

Hi I’m trying to create a horizontal slide where each horizontal page will have a button that will call a Dialog but onClick is not working in extends Pageradapter can anyone tell me what I’m doing wrong?
I gave the name onClickApprove to onClick that I want you to call Dialog. This Dialog is calling an Activity with a Ratingbar to make an assessment.
Thank you.

```
public class SliderAdapterUsado extends PagerAdapter {

    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    BottomSheetDialog dialog;

    Button show;

    public SliderAdapterUsado(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String[] slide_rota ={
            "Titulo1",
            "Titulo2"
    };

    public String[] slide_nome={
            "Descrção do titulo 1",
            "Descrção do titulo 2"
    };

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return slide_rota.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
        return view == (LinearLayout) object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){

        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.slide_layout_usados, container, false);

        TextView slideHeading = view.findViewById(R.id.slide_rota);
        TextView slideDescricao = view.findViewById(R.id.slide_nome);

        slideHeading.setText(slide_rota[position]);
        slideDescricao.setText(slide_nome[position]);

        container.addView(view);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object){

        container.removeView((LinearLayout)object);
    }

    public void onClickAvaliar(View view) {
        show = view.findViewById(R.id.show);

        dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(dialog.getContext());

        show.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                createDialog();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

        dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    }

    private void createDialog(){
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_rating, null, false);

        Button FeedBack = view.findViewById(R.id.FeedBack);

        FeedBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.setContentView(view);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please read [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button#HandlingEvents).

Note this in particular (emphasis mine):

> To define the click event handler for a button, add the android:onClick attribute to the  element in your XML layout. The value for this attribute must be the name of the method you want to call in response to a click event. **The Activity hosting the layout must then implement the corresponding method.**

The expectation is that the value set on the `onClick` xml attribute will be a method on the hosting `Activity`. Yours is in the adapter. That's why it doesn't work.

So either move that method to the hosting activity, or just handle the click event explicitly:

```
...
TextView slideHeading = view.findViewById(R.id.slide_rota);
TextView slideDescricao = view.findViewById(R.id.slide_nome);
Button slideButton = view.findViewById(R.id.slide_button);
slideButton.setOnClickListener (...)
...
```

Comment: How can you see me already I have add the attribute android:onClick to the element in its XML layout but it still doesn’t recognize as onClick because I have extends PagerAdapter.

Comment: Please rephrase - that made no sense to me.